# Converting date into integer (1 to 365)

Tags: sql, date, postgresql-9.4

I have no idea if there is a function in postgres to do that, but how can I convert a date (yyyy-mm-dd) into the numeric correspondent in SQL?

E.g. table input

```
id    | date
------+-------------
1     | 2013-01-01       
2     | 2013-01-02         
3     | 2013-02-01
```

Output

```
id    | date
------+-------------
1     | 1       
2     | 2         
3     | 32
```

Comment: You might want to check this out 

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function with the `doy`("**D**ay **O**f **Y**ear") argument, not `day` ("day of the week"):

```
select id, extract(doy from "date") 
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [this documentation](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff) an other option is to do something like:

```
SELECT id, DATE_PART('day', date - date_trunc('year', date)) + 1 as date
from table_name;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fb7d1/4) you can see a sql-fiddle.